# Android Studio Designer Wrong Dimensions

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

No matter what I try I cannot get the layout desiger in Android Studio to match my custom size and dpi virtual image. In specific I have a 1280x800 180dpi virtual device which correctly renders itself (trying to match custom hardware) but the layout designer is still off each time. Tried re-creating the virtual image and forcing the DPi in the config.ini. Reloaded Android Studio a few times.

Working on Mac 5K Retina and even tried going into native resolution but still not rendering in layout designer as expected.

[image]

On the left is the designer which clearly shows I am positioning the button in the center of the screen, however it is off in the virtual image.

I know I can layout dynamically and so forth. I am more looking for an answer if there is a know issue (and workaround) with the layout designer in Android Studio.

**Update**
It seems that Layout Designer is ignoring (?) the `hw.lcd.density` setting in the `config.ini` and defaults to 160dpi. I know that for a device with 8.35" physical screen the dpi should be 180 but for some reason even when creating the virtual device, it defaults to 180 or if I play with screen sizes, it may go to 240dpi but I cannot get it to produce a 180dpi virtual image.

Any assistance on how to create a virtual image with 1280x800 and 180 dpi would be appreciated that the layout designer can adhere to and work with 180dpi (and not 160)